# Specified module does not exist Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

Can you tell me why I cannot use below CLI? It says `Specified module does not exist`. Same error for both CLI commands.

**Note:** I have upgraded this app from `ng 5` to `ng 6`. Is that this error due to some issue on upgrading?

```
ng generate component messages --module=core

ng generate component messages --module=app
```

[image]

*app.core.module.ts*

```
export class CoreModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule
    };
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
export class AppModule { }
```

*ng --version*

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
... service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.3.2
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 6.3.2
@angular/tsc-wrapped              0.5.2
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "Abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "run-s build:client build:aot build:server",
    "buildclient": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --app 0",
    "build:aot": "ng build --aot --app 1",
    "build:server": "webpack -p",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "ng build --prod =cd dist http-server",
    "build:firebase": "ng build --prod && cp src/manifest_app.json dist && firebase deploy"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/service-worker": "6.0.7",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@cloudinary/angular": "^2.1.1",
    "@jaspero/ng2-confirmations": "^0.3.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^0.36.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "^5.0.1",
    "cloudinary-core": "^2.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng-pwa-tools": "0.0.15",
    "ng2-cloudinary": "^0.9.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-img-max": "^2.1.15",
    "ng4-geoautocomplete": "^0.1.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.5.0",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "^0.1.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.26.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "swiper": "^3.4.2",
    "webrtc-adapter": "^6.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.7",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.18",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to specify file name like this `ng generate component messages --module=app.module.ts`.

Comment: Same error for this too: `ng generate component messages --module=app.module.ts` @hrdkisback

Answer (score 18):

Below code works on latest CLI version.

`ng generate component messages --module app.core.module`

It doesn't requires `.ts`

If we want to create new component which points to specified module inside the folder, specify folder path. Folder path should root of app folder.

```
ng g c ./components/messages/messages --module message.module
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this worked for creating a component under a folder where Module name is different from Folder name

Answer (score 13):

Please use the path relative to your `base-href` that is `src/app`

Try

```
ng generate component messages --module ./app.core.module.ts
```

Comment: Same error for this too: `ng generate component messages --module ./core.module`

Comment: Sorry, I missed `.ts` please retry.

Comment: Same error for this too: `ng generate component messages --module ./core.module.ts`

Comment: Whats your current directory location?

Comment: Please see my post's image above.

Comment: Your module name was incorrect in command . Please retry with updated .

Comment: Same error for this too: `ng generate component messages --module ./app.core.module.ts`

Comment: Same command working on my side.  Hope your module should be annotated with `@NgModule`.

Comment: Yes, It is there on all modules.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon this issue and solved it by using a command like below:

```
ng g c core/header --module core/core.module.ts
```

I used this command and **got error**:

```
ng g c core/header --module core.module.ts
```

Comment: Yes, for modules in subfolders I also had to specify the path twice like this, or else change to the subfolder first.

Answer (score 4):

You can save yourself time and effort, instead of adding the command `--module ../path/to/name.module` each time for a new component, just add this configuration in your `angular.json` file:

```
 "projects": {
    "projectName": {
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "module": "../path/to/name.module"
       //.... other config
```

After that you can add a component as you would normally.

Comment: how do you define multiple modules

Answer (score 2):

Just to update below command worked for me :

> ng g c complete-path-of-folder/ComponentName --module
> ../complete-path-of-folder/home.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

you must create a routing (in the parent componenet) before create a module.

```
ng g m componentParent --routing --flat true
```

after that ou can create a module:

```
ng g c messages --module coupens
```

NB: dont forget to delete ComponenetParentModule from app.module (or parentModule)